# Ubuntu 13.10 no sound output

Tags: sound, upgrade, alsa

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04 I have no sound output devices listed on the sound settings and therefor no sound..

I have tried running `sudo alsa force-reload` and restarting but neither helped.

**This is how my sound settings looks like:**

[image: sound settings]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of `alsamixer`?

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix

```
sudo chmod o+x /run/user/1000/pulse
```

where 1000 - your user id

Comment: This works perfectly, why the downvote?

Comment: There is probably more than one situation and it was not the solution for someone for example it doesn't work for me...